# SharePoint 2007 Calculator

Tags: sharepoint, calculator

Does anyone know how to create a simple calculator using CEWPs or Form Web Parts on SharePoint 2007? Basically all I need is two fields for input and a submit button which uses the 2 input fields in a function and then gives the answer.

Sounds simple but everything I've tried (using html and javascript) produces an error in SharePoint, even if it works in a normal html page!!

Thanks in advance,
Karl

```
  <HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Saves Calculator</TITLE>

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

  function CalculateSaves(Atext, Btext, form)
  {
  var A = parseFloat(Atext);
  var B = parseFloat(Btext);
  form.Answer.value = ((((A * B)/60)/60)/7.33)/19;
  }

  function ClearForm(form)
  {
  form.input_A.value = "";
  form.input_B.value = "";
  form.Answer.value = "";
  }

  </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>

  <P><FONT SIZE="+2">Saves Calculator</FONT></P>

  <FORM NAME="Calculator" METHOD="post">
  <P>Time in Seconds: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT VALUE="30" NAME="input_A" SIZE=10>   Activities: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_B" SIZE=10></P>

  <P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate Saves" name="AddButton" onClick="CalculateSaves(this.form.input_A.value, this.form.input_B.value, this.form)">   <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Reset" name="ClearButton" onClick="ClearForm(this.form)"></P>

  <P>Saves = <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Answer" SIZE=12></P>
  </FORM>

  </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

Comment: @Shoban Sorry! The error is "'this.form.input_A.value' is null or not an object" but it works in a normal webpage, just not SharePoint.

Comment: can you post your code? instead of this.form.input..... " just use the ID.

Comment: @Shoban I have pasted my code above and will try your suggestion now and report back! Thanks.

Comment: @Shoban I get NaN when I use the ID so still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

1. Move the html and javascript to a notepad file, save as .html
2. Upload to document library
3. Add a Page Viewer webpart to your page, and link it to the html file saved within the library

This should now work.